# Does the exponential map of a Lie Group satisfy a universal property?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, and let $exp: \mathfrak{g} \to G$ be the exponential map. The map $exp$ gives a diffeomorphism of a neighborhood of the identity $0_{\mathfrak{g}}$ in $\mathfrak{g}$ with a neighborhood of the identity $1_{G}$ in $G$, and the linearization $exp_{*}: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ is the identity map up to an identification. Does $exp$ satisfy a Universal Property? In particular , does any map $f: \mathfrak{g} \to G$ satisfying the above properties factor as $g \circ exp$ for some smooth homomorphism $g: G \to G$? My apologies if this is a trivial question, I am still very much a beginner in Lie Theory.

Comment: I think this is a very nice question, but the answer cannot go in the direction you expect. If $g$ is a homomorpism such that $(g\circ exp)_*$ is the identity then the derivative of $g$ in $e$ must be the identity. This implies that $g$ equals the identity on the connected component of $e$, and thus $g\circ exp=exp$. I would believe that a charatcterization of $exp$ would rather work via the fact that the exponential curves $t\mapsto exp(tX)$ are one-parameter subgroups respectively that they solve an invariant ODE.

Comment: Thank you! I expected this would be true. Is it possible to find such a universal property that is similar though? One that is true if we lessen the restrictions on $f: \mathfrak{g} \to G$? For example, if the linearization $f_{*}: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ is scalar?

Comment: The problem is that the condition you impose boils down to the fact that the derviative in $0$ is the identity map, since this implies the local diffeomorphism property. So this says almost nothing about the exponential mapping. You have to go away from zero, and this is easier for the exponetial curves than for the exponential map.

Comment: Thank you for your help, from reading other comments and studying further it's become clear to me that what is truly "Universal" about $exp$ is how it classifies one parameter subgroups as you first said, and not such a property that I originally asked for. I think what I was thinking of was more along the lines of the role the Universal Covering group plays in the Finite dimensional Lie Algebra- simply connected Lie Group correspondence. .